# Syntax error on token “finally”, delete this token

Tags: java, android

```
public void GravaBanco(String nome, String telefone)
    try{ //Syntax error on token “try”, delete this token
        BancoDados = openOrCreateDatabase(NomeBanco, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO tabcadastropessoa (nomepessoa, telefonepessoa) VALUES (nomepessoa = '"+NomePessoa+"', telefonepessoa = '"+TelefonePessoa+"')";
        MensagemAlerta("Banco de Dados", "Registro gravado com sucesso!");
    } catch(Exception erro) { //Syntax error on tokens, delete this tokens
        MensagemAlerta("Erro no Banco de Dados", "Não foi possivel gravar o registro!" + erro);         
    } finally { //Syntax error on token “finally”, delete this token
        BancoDados.close();
}
```

Comment: Help us help you. No caps, actually ask a question, what are you trying to do, what did happen, how did you test it...

Comment: Add a stack trace to your question.

Comment: You could go back to your question (there's an edit function) and make it a better one? If you read the FAQ of this site, the object is to obtain a body of knowledge that can help other users, not just a forum where you dump your issue. So add a question, describe your problem and goals etc. And besides, even if you are a first time user, it is kinda polite to not just dump code, but to actually, you know.. ask for help?

Answer (score 5):

The try/finally blocks should be *inside* the function, like so:

```
public void GravaBanco(String nome, String telefone) {
  try {
    ...
  } finally {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, you are missing braces.

```
public void GravaBanco(String nome, String telefone){

        try{ //Syntax error on token “try”, delete this token
            BancoDados = openOrCreateDatabase(NomeBanco, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
            String SQL = "INSERT INTO tabcadastropessoa (nomepessoa, telefonepessoa) VALUES (nomepessoa = '"+NomePessoa+"', telefonepessoa = '"+TelefonePessoa+"')";
            MensagemAlerta("Banco de Dados", "Registro gravado com sucesso!");
        }catch(Exception erro){ //Syntax error on tokens, delete this tokens
            MensagemAlerta("Erro no Banco de Dados", "Não foi possivel gravar o registro!" + erro);         
        }
        finally{ //Syntax error on token “finally”, delete this token
            BancoDados.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think u missed the braces after method name try this code

```
    public void GravaBanco(String nome, String telefone) {
    try { // Syntax error on token “try”, delete this token
        BancoDados = openOrCreateDatabase(NomeBanco, MODE_WORLD_READABLE,
                null);
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO tabcadastropessoa (nomepessoa, telefonepessoa) VALUES (nomepessoa = '"
                + NomePessoa
                + "', telefonepessoa = '"
                + TelefonePessoa
                + "')";
        MensagemAlerta("Banco de Dados", "Registro gravado com sucesso!");
    } catch (Exception erro) { // Syntax error on tokens, delete this tokens
        MensagemAlerta("Erro no Banco de Dados",
                "Não foi possivel gravar o registro!" + erro);
    } finally { // Syntax error on token “finally”, delete this token
        BancoDados.close();
    }
}
```